kubernetes SERVICE for nginx doesnt work
POD nginx-pod is runs HTTP server listening on port 9000.
SERVICE nginx-svc (ClusterIP) for it, is created.
Yaml files at the bottom of the post.
kubectl get po -ntest -o wide
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-curl   1/1     Running   0          57s   172.16.158.37   worker-node02   <none>           <none>
nginx-pod    1/1     Running   0          17m   172.16.87.229   worker-node01   <none>           <none>

kubectl -ntest get svc
NAME        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
nginx-svc   ClusterIP   172.17.22.178   <none>        9000/TCP   11s

Problem/Question:
When I "curl" FROM: pod nginx-curl TO: nginx-pod IP 172.16.87.229 (the one with nginx listening on port 9000), it works:
 $ kubectl -ntest exec -it nginx-curl -- bash
 root@nginx-curl:/# curl  172.16.87.229:9000
 Works!

When I "curl" FROM: pod nginx-curl TO: nginx-svc IP 172.17.22.178 it doe not work:
$ kubectl -ntest exec -it nginx-curl -- bash
root@nginx-curl:/# curl 172.17.22.178:9000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.22.178 port 9000: Connection refused

What am I doing wrong?
Why nginx-svc is useless?
My YAML files used for this test:
nginx-pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: aaa
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx:1.16
      command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
      args: ["sed -i 's/listen  .*/listen 9000;/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          name: "http-server"

nginx-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: aaa
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: aaa
    name: nginx-pod
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000


SOLUTION:
I deleted previously created SERVICE and created a new one, this time with the following command:
kubectl expose pod nginx-pod --type=ClusterIP --port=9000 --target-port=9000 --name=nginx-pod-svc -n test

kubectl -n test get svc
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
nginx-pod-svc   ClusterIP   172.17.4.156   <none>        9000/TCP   4m57s

Now, either from the any cluster's node OR from any POD i can reach this service like so:
curl 172.17.4.156:9000
Works!

Also, thanks to kubectl expose command I can build now proper service YAML file which looks like this:
Version as ClusterIP
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod-svc
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: aaa
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: aaa

Version as NodePort
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod-svc
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: aaa
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: aaa

